# How to return a dataset with nested datasets from datasnap server to client?

Tags: delphi, datasnap

I use Delphi Berlin. I have a sample datasnap server return a dataset to client, the dataset contain TDataSetField.

The server method:

```
unit ServerMethodsUnit1;

//...

implementation

uses Datasnap.DBClient;

function TServerMethods1.GetDataSet: TDataSet;
var D: TClientDataSet;
    D1: TDataSet;
    F: TFieldDef;
begin
  D := TClientDataSet.Create(nil);
  D.FieldDefs.Add('DocKey', ftLargeint);
  D.FieldDefs.Add('DocNo', ftWideString, 20);
  D.FieldDefs.Add('Detail', ftDataSet);
  F := D.FieldDefs.Find('Detail');
  F.ChildDefs.Add('DtlKey', ftLargeint);
  F.ChildDefs.Add('DocKey', ftLargeint);
  F.ChildDefs.Add('Amount', ftBcd, 2);
  D.CreateDataSet;

  D.Append;
  D.FindField('DocKey').AsLargeInt := 1;
  D.FindField('DocNo').AsString := 'IV-00001';
  D1 := (D.FindField('Detail') as TDataSetField).NestedDataSet;
  D1.AppendRecord([1, 1, 123.12]);
  D1.AppendRecord([2, 1, 234.23]);
  D.Post;
  Result := D;
end;

end.
```

The client:

```
unit Unit1;

//...

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var C: TServerMethods1Client;
    D: TDataSet;
begin
  C := TServerMethods1Client.Create(SQLConnection1.DBXConnection);
  try
    D := C.GetDataSet;
    //...
  finally
    C.DisposeOf;
  end;
end;
```

When the client call TServerMethods1Client.GetDataSet method, the datasnap server return an error **Feature not implemented.** Any ideas of how to return a dataset contains nested datasets from datasnap server to client?

Comment: Delphi's DBExpress could return a ClientDataSet with nested data from the outset, i.e. well before the D2009 extensions to DataSnap which introduced TServerMethods, etc, and DBX hasn't lost this ability.  So why don't you just return the nested data in the traditional DBX + CDS manner?

Comment: @MartynA - The actual server will be HTTP datasnap server. There are two server methods, first method return as TDataSet, second method return as TJSONValue (in easy to read format) where I have write classes to convert TDataSet to TJSONValue. For client written with delphi, client can call first server method to return TDataSet (without manually convert from TJSONValue to TDataSet); client not written with delphi required to manually parse TJSONValue return from second server method.

Comment: Hmm.  The only nested datasets I've worked with have been TClientDataSets and they usually work fine because the nested data is easily wrapped via a CDS's Data property.  Have you tried using CDSs oon the server and client side?

Comment: @MartynA - Thank you for your suggestion, it works. My answer as below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution.

The server method:

```
function TServerMethods1.GetDataSet: OleVariant;
//...
begin
  D := TClientDataSet.Create(nil);
  try
    //...   
    Result := D.Data;
  finally
    D.DisposeOf;
  end;
end;
```

The client:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var C: TServerMethods1Client;
begin
  C := TServerMethods1Client.Create(SQLConnection1.DBXConnection);
  try
    ClientDataSet1.Data := C.GetDataSet;
  finally
    C.DisposeOf;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You use .Data this ClientDataSet, nice!

Answer (score 0):

I use `DataSnap REST Application` (Server) and `DataSnap REST Client (Client)`. You can use **TFDJSONDataSets** (FireDac Reflect)

```
function TServerMethods1.GetDataSet: TFDJSONDataSets;
var 
  D: TClientDataSet;
  D1: TDataSet;
  F: TFieldDef;
begin
  D := TClientDataSet.Create(nil);
  D.FieldDefs.Add('DocKey', ftLargeint);
  D.FieldDefs.Add('DocNo', ftWideString, 20);
  D.FieldDefs.Add('Detail', ftDataSet);
  F := D.FieldDefs.Find('Detail');
  F.ChildDefs.Add('DtlKey', ftLargeint);
  F.ChildDefs.Add('DocKey', ftLargeint);
  F.ChildDefs.Add('Amount', ftBcd, 2);
  D.CreateDataSet;

  D.Append;
  D.FindField('DocKey').AsLargeInt := 1;
  D.FindField('DocNo').AsString := 'IV-00001';
  D1 := (D.FindField('Detail') as TDataSetField).NestedDataSet;
  D1.AppendRecord([1, 1, 123.12]);
  D1.AppendRecord([2, 1, 234.23]);
  D.Post;

  TFDJSONDataSetsWriter.ListAdd(Result,'DATASET',D);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 LDataSetList: TFDJSONDataSets;
 LDataSet: TFDDataSet;
begin     
  try
    LDataSet := TFDJSONDataSetsReader.GetListValueByName(LDataSetList, 'D');    
    if (oFDMemTable.Active) then
      oFDMemtable.Close;
    oFDMemTable.AppendData(LDataSet);
  except
    on E: TDSRestProtocolException do
      HandleRestException(ClientModule1.DSRestConnection, 'Error', E)
    else
      raise;
  end;  
end;
```

I pass some examples:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/Data.FireDACJSONReflect.TFDJSONDataSets
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Tutorial:_Using_a_REST_DataSnap_Server_with_an_Application_and_FireDAC